# Can't update Google Chrome in Iran

Tags: updates, google-chrome, google

Google lets users in Iran to download chrome deb from google.com/chrome, however the repo dl.google.com/linux is inaccessible!

So running apt-get update and upgrade results in a lot of error messages.

Is there an alternate repo for Chrome?

Comment: Your Ubuntu release is?

Comment: @A.B. 15.10 x64

Comment: I use proxychains and socks over ssh, very fast and easy!

Comment: @Daniyal Any link to a guide on using proxychains with apt? Do you use a http proxy or a socks one?

Comment: `sudo proxychains apt-get update`, don't forget to config proxychains through it's config file. I'm using socks proxy over ssh (You can have a free ssh with openshift)

Comment: @Daniyal Thanks much. It worked. Damet Garm dadsh!

Comment: Ghorbuned dada!

Answer (score 3):

Using [Tor](https://www.torproject.org/) and `torify`

```
sudo apt-add-repository universe
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install tor
sudo apt-get install torsocks
```

If `tor` and `torsocks` is also not available, run (for Ubuntu Trusty)

```
wget https://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/universe/t/tor/tor_0.2.4.27-1build0.14.04.‌​1_amd64.deb
wget https://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/universe/t/torsocks/torsocks_1.3-3_amd64.d‌​eb
sudo dpkg -i tor*.deb
```

After that use `torify`

```
sudo torify apt-get update
sudo torify apt-get install google-chrome-stable
```

Comment: You can try to use HTTPS for those URLs, if they're blocked based on deep packet inspection.

Comment: On the other hand, the ISP may also block TLS connections to that IP address. So it's worth to give both variants a try.

Comment: @A.B. Tor doesn't work here, unfortunately. It is blocked too.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do it using tsocks and shadowsocks:

```
sudo apt-get install tsocks
sudo tsocks apt-get update
sudo tsocks apt-get upgrade
```

Anyway this is still slow and annoying. I wish Canonical could work with Google to unblock the repo, or host chrome debs somewhere else.